# Table within the page

Tags: tables, fontsize, paper-size, dimensions

I'm using a package of Rstudio that gives me tables in Latex code.  Unfortunately, the table that I get is huge and goes outside the edges of the page. I've already tried `\small` but it is not enough. I've read about `\resizebox` or `\adjustbox`, but they seem don't work... (I'm sure that I'm not able to apply them. It is my first time with Latex)

This is my code

```
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-9} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{8}{c}{log(tpens)} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8)\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 sex & 0.226$^{***}$ & 0.219$^{***}$ & 0.239$^{***}$ & 0.244$^{***}$ & 0.131$^{***}$ & 0.132$^{***}$ & 0.132$^{***}$ & 0.142$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.020) & (0.019) & (0.017) & (0.017) & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.016) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 eta &  & $-$0.009$^{***}$ & $-$0.005$^{***}$ & $-$0.004$^{***}$ & $-$0.002$^{**}$ & $-$0.002$^{**}$ & $-$0.002$^{**}$ & $-$0.002$^{*}$ \\ 
  &  & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 studio\_lev2 &  &  & 0.330$^{***}$ & 0.163$^{***}$ & 0.129$^{***}$ & 0.127$^{***}$ & 0.127$^{***}$ & 0.129$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 studio\_lev3 &  &  & 0.717$^{***}$ & 0.459$^{***}$ & 0.420$^{***}$ & 0.417$^{***}$ & 0.417$^{***}$ & 0.431$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  & (0.035) & (0.038) & (0.036) & (0.036) & (0.036) & (0.036) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 type\_job\_Middle-class\_worker &  &  &  & 0.219$^{***}$ & 0.189$^{***}$ & 0.187$^{***}$ & 0.187$^{***}$ & 0.191$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 type\_job\_Manager &  &  &  & 0.465$^{***}$ & 0.418$^{***}$ & 0.414$^{***}$ & 0.414$^{***}$ & 0.410$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  & (0.039) & (0.037) & (0.037) & (0.037) & (0.036) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 type\_job\_Self-Employed &  &  &  & $-$0.142$^{***}$ & $-$0.189$^{***}$ & $-$0.190$^{***}$ & $-$0.189$^{***}$ & $-$0.173$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  & (0.022) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.020) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 acontrib &  &  &  &  & 0.020$^{***}$ & 0.020$^{***}$ & 0.020$^{***}$ & 0.019$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 dislav &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.085$^{***}$ & $-$0.085$^{***}$ & $-$0.050$^{*}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.027) & (0.027) & (0.027) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 occnow &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.029 & 0.075 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.072) & (0.073) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.147$^{*}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.080) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.005 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.032) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.054 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.039) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg5 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.012 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.034) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.067 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.050) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg7 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.080$^{*}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.043) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg8 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.076$^{**}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.036) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg9 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.018 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.033) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg10 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.071 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.045) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg11 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.050 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.041) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg12 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.012 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.038) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg13 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.099$^{*}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.060) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg14 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.217$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.056) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg15 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.091$^{**}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.039) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg16 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.120$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.040) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg17 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.176$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.054) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg18 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.019 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.046) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg19 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.126$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.044) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 ireg20 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.021 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.039) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
 Constant & 6.860$^{***}$ & 7.530$^{***}$ & 7.133$^{***}$ & 7.034$^{***}$ & 6.273$^{***}$ & 6.324$^{***}$ & 6.266$^{***}$ & 6.171$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) & (0.089) & (0.082) & (0.078) & (0.082) & (0.083) & (0.166) & (0.170) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 2,229 & 2,229 & 2,229 & 2,226 & 2,173 & 2,173 & 2,173 & 2,173 \\ 
R$^{2}$ & 0.056 & 0.081 & 0.270 & 0.358 & 0.455 & 0.457 & 0.457 & 0.476 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.056 & 0.080 & 0.269 & 0.356 & 0.453 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.469 \\ 
Residual Std. Error & 0.406 (df = 2227) & 0.400 (df = 2226) & 0.357 (df = 2224) & 0.335 (df = 2218) & 0.309 (df = 2164) & 0.309 (df = 2163) & 0.309 (df = 2162) & 0.305 (df = 2143) \\ 
F Statistic & 133.081$^{***}$ (df = 1; 2227) & 97.706$^{***}$ (df = 2; 2226) & 206.134$^{***}$ (df = 4; 2224) & 176.461$^{***}$ (df = 7; 2218) & 225.471$^{***}$ (df = 8; 2164) & 202.428$^{***}$ (df = 9; 2163) & 182.131$^{***}$ (df = 10; 2162) & 67.151$^{***}$ (df = 29; 2143) \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{8}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

This is what I get
[image: Table]

How Can I solve?? I need something that reduce all these empty spaces between the columns and the rows in order to fit the table into the page

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: hi @JoséCarlosSantos and thank for the answer. I've update the question with the working code. I think now it should be complete

Comment: What you describe as extra empty spaces between columns is caused by the relatively wide entries in the last two rows of your table. For less horizontal space betewwn adjacent columns, you may also want to consider removing `@{\extracolsep{5pt}}`.

Comment: hi @leandriis and thank for the help.  I've tried to remove this piece `{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccccccc} ` but i get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMQRT.png  . If I leave `\begin{tabular}{@lcccccccc}` it doesn't work at all instead

Comment: @leandriis which one of the 2 last rows of the code should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the degrees-of-freedom (df) information on separate lines, you don't need to cast the table in landscape format. Since the table has more rows than can fit on a page, I suggest you employ a [longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) environment instead of a `table`/`tabular` combination.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % align numbers in columns on decimal markers
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next four instructions
\small      % 10% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out inter-column space
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % see p. 7 of package's user guide
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{d{2.5}} d{2.6} @{}} 

%% headers and footers
\caption{X} \label{tab:x} \\
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{$\log(\mathrm{tpens})$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-9} 
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} 
& \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)}\\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{$\log(\mathrm{tpens})$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-9} 
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} 
& \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)}\\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

% empty final footer
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
 sex & 0.226^{***} & 0.219^{***} & 0.239^{***} & 0.244^{***} & 0.131^{***} & 0.132^{***} & 0.132^{***} & 0.142^{***} \\ 
  & (0.020) & (0.019) & (0.017) & (0.017) & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.016) \\ 
\addlinespace
 eta & & -0.009^{***} & -0.005^{***} & -0.004^{***} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{*} \\ 
  & & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 studio\_lev2 & & & 0.330^{***} & 0.163^{***} & 0.129^{***} & 0.127^{***} & 0.127^{***} & 0.129^{***} \\ 
  & & & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 studio\_lev3 & & & 0.717^{***} & 0.459^{***} & 0.420^{***} & 0.417^{***} & 0.417^{***} & 0.431^{***} \\ 
  & & & (0.035) & (0.038) & (0.036) & (0.036) & (0.036) & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Middle-class\_worker & & & & 0.219^{***} & 0.189^{***} & 0.187^{***} & 0.187^{***} & 0.191^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Manager & & & & 0.465^{***} & 0.418^{***} & 0.414^{***} & 0.414^{***} & 0.410^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.039) & (0.037) & (0.037) & (0.037) & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Self-Employed & & & & -0.142^{***} & -0.189^{***} & -0.190^{***} & -0.189^{***} & -0.173^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.022) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.020) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 acontrib & & & & & 0.020^{***} & 0.020^{***} & 0.020^{***} & 0.019^{***} \\ 
          & & & & & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 dislav & & & & & & -0.085^{***} & -0.085^{***} & -0.050^{*} \\ 
        & & & & & & (0.027) & (0.027) & (0.027) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 occnow & & & & & & &  0.029  &  0.075 \\ 
        & & & & & & & (0.072) & (0.073) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg2 & & & & & & & &  0.147^{*} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.080) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg3 & & & & & & & & -0.005 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.032) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg4 & & & & & & & & -0.054 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg5 & & & & & & & & -0.012 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.034) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg6 & & & & & & & & 0.067 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.050) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg7 & & & & & & & & -0.080^{*} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.043) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg8 & & & & & & & &  0.076^{**} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg9 & & & & & & & & -0.018 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.033) \\ 
\addlinespace      
 ireg10 & & & & & & & & -0.071 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.045) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg11 & & & & & & & &  0.050 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.041) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg12 & & & & & & & &  0.012 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.038) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg13 & & & & & & & & -0.099^{*} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.060) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg14 & & & & & & & & -0.217^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.056) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg15 & & & & & & & & -0.091^{**} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg16 & & & & & & & & -0.120^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.040) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg17 & & & & & & & & -0.176^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.054) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg18 & & & & & & & & -0.019 \\
        & & & & & & & & (0.046) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg19 & & & & & & & & -0.126^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.044) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg20 & & & & & & & & -0.021 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 Constant & 6.860^{***} & 7.530^{***} & 7.133^{***} & 7.034^{***} & 6.273^{***} & 6.324^{***} & 6.266^{***} & 6.171^{***} \\ 
          & (0.015) & (0.089) & (0.082) & (0.078) & (0.082) & (0.083) & (0.166) & (0.170) \\ 
  
\midrule

Observations & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}226} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} \\ 
$R^{2}$ & 0.056 & 0.081 & 0.270 & 0.358 & 0.455 & 0.457 & 0.457 & 0.476 \\ 
Adjusted $R^{2}$ & 0.056 & 0.080 & 0.269 & 0.356 & 0.453 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.469 \\ 
Resid.\ Std.\ Error & 0.406 & 0.400 & 0.357 & 0.335 & 0.309 & 0.309 & 0.309 & 0.305 \\ 
\qquad df & \mc{2227} & \mc{2226} & \mc{2224} & \mc{2218} & \mc{2164} & \mc{2163} & \mc{2162} & \mc{2143} \\
$F$-Statistic 
& \mc{133.081} & \mc{97.706} & \mc{206.134} & \mc{176.461} & \mc{225.471 } & \mc{202.428} & \mc{182.131} & \mc{67.151} \\ 
\qquad df & \mc{1;2227} & \mc{2;2226} & \mc{4;2224} & \mc{7;2218} & \mc{8;2164} & \mc{9;2163} & \mc{10;2162} & \mc{29;2143}  \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\textit{Note}: $^{*}\ p<0.1$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{***}\ p<0.01$} \\  
\end{longtable} 
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: hi @Mico thank you very much! I'm gonna to study this code to replicate it for all my other tables